# I want to install in my project directory :frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:npm (npm install) @ semagrow-webgui: but I'm getting this error #19579

Tags: maven, npm, maven-plugin, npm-install

While building, I encountered this error.Any idea what the error is please?

Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:npm

Comment: Please add some more info to your question. What commands did you tried. What version of npm do you use.

Comment: I want to Install npm version 4.0.2